# how can i get HSV color upper and lower range?

Tags: numpy, opencv, contour, hsv

I'm currently finding the contour using hsv upper and lower ranges of red, blue, green and yellow. Its working fine but can any one help me to share all hsv upper and lower ranges of the following colors:

```
#61366B
#5B66AF
#E7FF00
#FF0000
#FF6700
#C21CE5
#45AFAC
#0D9910
#0033C1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors

# Define our colours - presumably RGB
h = ['#61366a','#5B66AF','#E7FF00', '#FF0000','#FF6700','#C21CE5','#45AFAC','#0D9910','#0033C1']

# Convert to floats
RGB = [matplotlib.colors.to_rgb(c) for c in h]

# Make into Numpy array of floats, reshape and convert to HSV
HSV = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(RGB,np.float32).reshape(-1,1,3), cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)

# Print maxima and minima
print(f'Hue: min {np.min(HSV[...,0])}, max {np.max(HSV[...,0])}')
print(f'Sat: min {np.min(HSV[...,1])}, max {np.max(HSV[...,1])}')
print(f'Val: min {np.min(HSV[...,2])}, max {np.max(HSV[...,2])}')
```

**Sample Output**

```
Hue: min 0.0, max 289.6153564453125
Sat: min 0.47999992966651917, max 0.9999998807907104
Val: min 0.4156862795352936, max 1.0
```

Be very aware that **OpenCV** expects a different range of values depending on the image type!!!

Comment: {np.min(HSV[...,0])  
the above line means what?

Comment: Note that I just edited my code, so please re-copy. `np.min(X)` means the minimum value in `X`. `HSV[...,0]` means the 0th channel of every row and column, i.e. the H channel. The `...` means *"all the other indices I couldn't bothered to type, or I don't know"*.

Comment: The curly braces are an *"f-string"*. To print the value of variable `Total`, use `f'Value={Total}'`